# Sectioned UITableView refreshing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my application is the UITableView in popover, which reloading when new data. If table not sectioned, all works perfect with this code:

Notification, which initiate reloading:

```
- (void)recieveNotification:(NSNotification*) notification {
if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"NewDataArrived"]) {
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

Method that reloads:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//Formation of the new content of table

[self.tableView reloadData];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

But if I sort content by sections, everything goes to chaos. View not reloading and new data just adding to the end of table, into last section.

Headers for sections:

```
- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section == 0) {
    return @"Cities";
} else
    if (section == 1) {
        return @"Hotels";
    } else 
        if (section == 2) {
            return @"Airports";
        } else
return @"Landmarks";
}
```

[Here is screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8288064/img/chaos.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8288064/img/chaos.png).

I've spent a lot of time on this trouble and will be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this buddy!!!!

.h

```
   -(void)myOwnMethod:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
-(void)myOwnMethod:(id)sender{

    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
- (void)recieveNotification:(NSNotification*) notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"NewDataArrived"]) {
            //  [self viewWillAppear:YES];

        [self myOwnMethod];

    }
}
```